# Debug character devices (mouse, keyboard, touch screen etc) and read input data

Tags: debugging, usb-device

I am working on a project where I have a infrared [multi-touch frame](https://keetouch.eu/en/wkmi-0320) connected to the PC via USB cable, whenever an object, eg, a hand/finger, passes through it, it acts as a mouse.

What I want to do is to be able to print out the coordinates where the object has passed. I was thinking if I can understand how the device communicates communicates with the PC then I can write some program (if it is possible) that prints out the coordinates in terms of x and y values. I have read that these type of devices is also known as character devices and was wondering if there is a way to debug them and read the input it sends to the computer (I assume they send input about the x and y coordinates where my hand passed and that way the mouse cursor moves there).

This is not my field of study as I am a computer engineer so I have no idea how to start. Any tip would be appreciated. Thanks in advance..

Here is `lsusb` output:

```
mohammedaabdu@Mohammed-HP-Pavilion-Gaming-Notebook:~$ lsusb -D /dev/bus/usb/001/008
Device: ID 1870:010d Nexio Co., Ltd 
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x1870 Nexio Co., Ltd
  idProduct          0x010d 
  bcdDevice            5.a1
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0029
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xc0
      Self Powered
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.11
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength     736
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               1
```

and here is dmesg output:

```
[ 7907.643318] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[ 7907.792675] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1870, idProduct=010d, bcdDevice= 5.a1
[ 7907.792681] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 7907.792684] usb 1-1: Product: Nexio HID Multi-Touch ATI0320-10
[ 7907.792687] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Nexio Touch Device (HS)
[ 7907.798615] input: Nexio Touch Device (HS) Nexio HID Multi-Touch ATI0320-10 Touchscreen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:1870:010D.0002/input/input22
[ 7907.855645] input: Nexio Touch Device (HS) Nexio HID Multi-Touch ATI0320-10 Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:1870:010D.0002/input/input23
[ 7907.856502] input: Nexio Touch Device (HS) Nexio HID Multi-Touch ATI0320-10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:1870:010D.0002/input/input24
[ 7907.857637] hid-generic 0003:1870:010D.0002: input,hiddev1,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Nexio Touch Device (HS) Nexio HID Multi-Touch ATI0320-10] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input0
[ 7908.181472] input: Nexio Touch Device (HS) Nexio HID Multi-Touch ATI0320-10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:1870:010D.0002/input/input26
[ 7908.182031] input: Nexio Touch Device (HS) Nexio HID Multi-Touch ATI0320-10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:1870:010D.0002/input/input28
[ 7908.182632] hid-multitouch 0003:1870:010D.0002: input,hiddev1,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Nexio Touch Device (HS) Nexio HID Multi-Touch ATI0320-10] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it already behaves like a mouse you can get the coordinates directly from the mouse events.

There are many ways to do that. For example a python program, with the library [python-libinput](https://python-libinput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html#pointerevent).

`xev` will also show you the events.

Or, as root, `evtest`, that will print a human readable version of what you would read from `/dev/ìnput/eventX`.

Some pieces of hardware show themselves to the system as multiple devices (for example, a mouse and a keyboard).

```
xinput --list
```

will tell you the input devices you have (you can unplug it and replug it to see the differences if you are not sure which one is the right one).

In these cases you will not be accessing the raw data, but the raw events.

That should get you started. There is plenty on documentation on `libinput`.

Comment: Thanks, it seems like it behaves both as a touchscreen and as a mouse from the output in dmesg. I will read more about it. Hope it helps with my project! :)

Comment: Good luck. Remember to mark the answers to your questions as helpful and/or as the solution (if either option is the case). You can also mark comments as helpful.